# Unknown NullPointerException when creating simple player

Tags: nullpointerexception, java-me, video-player, mmapi

I am trying to write a simple player but on running this code, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
 try {

            player = Manager.createPlayer("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Movie_0001.3gp");
            player.realize();
            VideoControl vc;
            vc=(VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
            if(vc!=null){
                Item video=(Item) vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
                playerFrm=new Form("playing video");
                playerFrm.append(video);
                display=display.getDisplay(this);
                display.setCurrent(playerFrm);
            }
           player.prefetch();
           player.start();

        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MediaException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: In this line:`display=display.getDisplay(this);`, was `display` initialized before?

Comment: Which line gives the nullpointer??

Answer (score 0):

`display=display.getDisplay` seems odd! Was display initialized before and are you overwriting it with a function from its own?

`getDisplay` probably should be some sort of static function

Answer (score 0):

you need to change in code Where you get cureent display,

`display=Display.getDisplay(this);`